# Using a spinner to create a certain number of timepickers

Tags: android, timepicker

I am designing a medication reminder app and I have chosen to use a spinner so that the user can choose to select "Once A Day", "Twice A Day" or "Three Times A Day".

I would then like to use the answer from the spinner to create 1, 2 or 3 timepickers as necessary.

The only problem is that I am getting really stuck on how to do this.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction??

Many Thanks

Sarah

Comment: add listener to your spinner, and according to the item selected - add different amount of views to the viewGroup.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out of your day to help me. I am going to have a problem look at this suggestion and get my head around it but already I see what you mean.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create Array in strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="time_arrays">
    <item>Once A Day</item>
    <item>Twice A Day</item>
    <item>Three Times A Day</item>
</string-array>
```

**Spinner arrayadapter Adapter**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_arrays));
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
yourspinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Initialize**

```
   private Spinner spnSemester;
    ArrayAdapter<String> timeAdapter;
    List<String>courseList= new ArrayList<>();



  spnTime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnTime);
    courseList.add("Once A Day");
    courseList.add("Twice A Day");
    courseList.add("Thrice A Day");
    timeAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,courseList);
    spnTime.setAdapter(timeAdapter);

timeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

**use on click Listener to get value**

```
spnTime.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Store selected value here

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially design your xml layout declaring `Spinner` and three `TimePicker`, more detail about `Spinner` [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Then hide and show timePicker as required.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {  

    String[] spinner_values = { "Once A Day", "Twice A Day", "Three Times A Day" };  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
         //setup timepickers as required
        timepicker1=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);  
        timepicker2=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);  
        timepicker3=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker3);  
        //initially set visibility to GONE for all three timers
        //setup spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner_values);  
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {  
        Switch(position){
            case 2 :
                //show timePicker3
            case 1:
                //show timepicker2
            case 0:
                //show timePicker1
                break;
            default
                //hide all timerPickers
                break;
        }  
    }
}
```